# how to save serialize array of javascript value store in PHP on SUBMIT

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, serializearray

I m using jquery datatables first time, so now i done table like this[image: Click to view Image]

everything works perfectly. now i m using this below javascript code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( 
        {
            "pageLength": 50,
            'sDom': 'l' ,
        } );
        $('#example tfoot th').each( function () 
        {
            var title = $('#example thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" style="width:100%;" id="munna_'+title+'" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
        });


        var table = $('#example').DataTable();
        table.columns().every( function () 
         {
        var that = this;
        $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
        that
        .search( this.value )
        .draw();
        });
        });


$('#munna_button').click( function()
   {
         var data = table.$('input, select').serialize();
        alert(JSON.stringify(data))
        return false;
    });
});
```

now this code returns value like this in **rate_14=67&rate_15=87&rate_67=88 etc..,**

now i dont have idea how to store this on SUBMIT. normally on submit i get $_POST['name'] like this, now please some one hlep me from this.

Comment: you need to call ajax. add ajax url where you need to accept post request in php.
`$.ajax({url:"", type:"POST", data:"serializeData"});`

Comment: @Munna try $.ajax() visit http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: but there is possible to enter more than 20 values so when i do in ajax it may take more time thats why i am asking on SUBMIT

Answer (score 1):

Simply use ajax to send the information:

```
$('#munna_button').click( function(){
      var data = table.$('input, select').serialize();
      $.post('url_link_here', data, function(returnData){
        //success -- do stuff with returnData if there is any

      }).fail(function(){
        //failed

      });
 });
```

Comment: there will be more then 100 records so the rate_14=67&rate_15=87&rate_67=88... will go so long ?? it wont affect and make slow ?

Comment: @Munna why would it be slow? Whether you actually submit all the information and refresh the page or send it via ajax your internet speed and  server capacity won't change. It'll be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the serialized data into a hidden variable added to form.
    
and in java script use some like this to save the value in hidden field

```
$('#serialize_data').val(JSON.stringify(data));
```

After the form is submitted, you will find the value in

```
$_POST['serialize_data']
```

If you don't want to submit the form , you can use ajax to send data to .php script
I hope this will help you